# How do I unit test a function which returns a query?

Tags: php, phpunit, propel

I'm using Propel ORM and I have a function which returns a query, I want to write unit tests for it to check if it spits out the correct query. I can create mock tables and then check if they the results of running the query are the same but I wonder if there's a better way.

I use `Propel ORM`.

Things that I tried:

String comparing the queries, doesn't work because I get parametrised query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just thinking aloud: you could use an SQL parsing library to parse the resultant query and see if certain components of the query exist or not, but I've been there before, and the problem is that these libraries focus on the MySQL dialect since PHP and MySQL are used together (most of the time, as an industrial standard).